# gradle experimental plugin is not recognizing android.applicationVariants.all

Tags: android, gradle

I recently migrated a project from gradle 2.1.0 to gradle experimental plugin 0.7.0

In my 2.1.0 script I had script for renaming the APK as per a specific naming convention. Name of the project, followed by version, date time.

The new gradle experimental plugin seems not to recognize this script anymore. Can anyone please help?

script that is not recognized by gradle experimental plugin is below.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def appName
    //Check if an applicationName property is supplied; if not use the name of the parent project.
    if (project.hasProperty("applicationName")) {
        appName = applicationName
    } else {
        appName = parent.name
    }

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def newApkName
        //If there's no ZipAlign task it means that our artifact will be unaligned and we need to mark it as such.
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            newApkName = "${appName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        } else {
            newApkName = "${appName}-${variant.versionName}-unaligned.apk"
        }
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName.replace(".apk", "-" + getDateTime() + ".apk"))
    }
}

import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def getDateTime() {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");

    return df.format(new Date());
}
```

Error is

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/vp/newconstruction/android-vpn/artifacts.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find property 'android' on project ':main'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much struggle I wanted to answer my own question without much of a choice.

From the official documentation of the gradle experimental plugin, it is clear that the plugin is still in it's early development. So many features of the experimental plugin do not work.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Answer (score 0):

@developer1011, Thanks for answering your own question. I too was renaming my APKs and AARs and was running into the issue with accessing the variants. I noticed more specifically that it talks about variant functionality being very, very limited right now.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

> The DSL for modifying variants and their tasks is very, very limited right now.